# Can't uninstall Ubuntu One and Banshee in Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: 11.10, software-center, uninstall

I recently upgraded my Google Cr-48 to Ubuntu 11.10 from Ubuntu 11.04. I have several questions.

- I try uninstalling Ubuntu One like I did previously (Why did it re-install?). It comes up with an error saying that it can't uninstall.
- I see Banshee is installed, and I can't uninstall it either.

Here is what the error message from Banshee read:

> Package operation failed
>
> The installation or removal of a software package failed.

Details:

```
installArchives() failed: (Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 197253 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing banshee-extension-soundmenu ...
Removing banshee ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Setting up samba4 (4.0.0~alpha17~git20110807.dfsg1-1ubuntu1) ...
Unknown parameter encountered: "max log size"
Ignoring unknown parameter "max log size"
Unknown parameter encountered: "syslog"
Ignoring unknown parameter "syslog"
Unknown parameter encountered: "unix password sync"
Ignoring unknown parameter "unix password sync"
Unknown parameter encountered: "passwd program"
Ignoring unknown parameter "passwd program"
Unknown parameter encountered: "pam password change"
Ignoring unknown parameter "pam password change"
Unknown parameter encountered: "map to guest"
Ignoring unknown parameter "map to guest"
Unknown parameter encountered: "usershare allow guests"
Ignoring unknown parameter "usershare allow guests"
Unknown parameter encountered: "username map"
Ignoring unknown parameter "username map"
Unknown parameter encountered: "writeable"
Ignoring unknown parameter "writeable"
Unknown parameter encountered: "guest ok"
Ignoring unknown parameter "guest ok"
Unknown parameter encountered: "max log size"
Ignoring unknown parameter "max log size"
Unknown parameter encountered: "syslog"
Ignoring unknown parameter "syslog"
Unknown parameter encountered: "unix password sync"
Ignoring unknown parameter "unix password sync"
Unknown parameter encountered: "passwd program"
Ignoring unknown parameter "passwd program"
Unknown parameter encountered: "pam password change"
Ignoring unknown parameter "pam password change"
Unknown parameter encountered: "map to guest"
Ignoring unknown parameter "map to guest"
Unknown parameter encountered: "usershare allow guests"
Ignoring unknown parameter "usershare allow guests"
Unknown parameter encountered: "username map"
Ignoring unknown parameter "username map"
Unknown parameter encountered: "writeable"
Ignoring unknown parameter "writeable"
Unknown parameter encountered: "guest ok"
Ignoring unknown parameter "guest ok"
module samba_dsdb initialization failed : No such object
Unable to load modules for /var/lib/samba/private/sam.ldb: dsdb_module_search_dn: did not find base dn @ROOTDSE (0 results)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/samba/setup/upgradeprovision", line 1716, in <module>
    ldbs = get_ldbs(paths, creds, session, lp)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/samba/upgradehelpers.py", line 156, in get_ldbs
    ldbs.sam = SamDB(paths.samdb, session_info=session, credentials=creds, lp=lp, options=["modules:samba_dsdb"])
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/samba/samdb.py", line 55, in __init__
    options=options)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/samba/__init__.py", line 114, in __init__
    self.connect(url, flags, options)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/samba/samdb.py", line 69, in connect
    options=options)
_ldb.LdbError: (80, 'dsdb_module_search_dn: did not find base dn @ROOTDSE (0 results)')
dpkg: error processing samba4 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Errors were encountered while processing:
 samba4
Setting up samba4 (4.0.0~alpha17~git20110807.dfsg1-1ubuntu1) ...
Unknown parameter encountered: "max log size"
Ignoring unknown parameter "max log size"
Unknown parameter encountered: "syslog"
Ignoring unknown parameter "syslog"
Unknown parameter encountered: "unix password sync"
Ignoring unknown parameter "unix password sync"
Unknown parameter encountered: "passwd program"
Ignoring unknown parameter "passwd program"
Unknown parameter encountered: "pam password change"
Ignoring unknown parameter "pam password change"
Unknown parameter encountered: "map to guest"
Ignoring unknown parameter "map to guest"
Unknown parameter encountered: "usershare allow guests"
Ignoring unknown parameter "usershare allow guests"
Unknown parameter encountered: "username map"
Ignoring unknown parameter "username map"
Unknown parameter encountered: "writeable"
Ignoring unknown parameter "writeable"
Unknown parameter encountered: "guest ok"
Ignoring unknown parameter "guest ok"
Unknown parameter encountered: "max log size"
Ignoring unknown parameter "max log size"
Unknown parameter encountered: "syslog"
Ignoring unknown parameter "syslog"
Unknown parameter encountered: "unix password sync"
Ignoring unknown parameter "unix password sync"
Unknown parameter encountered: "passwd program"
Ignoring unknown parameter "passwd program"
Unknown parameter encountered: "pam password change"
Ignoring unknown parameter "pam password change"
Unknown parameter encountered: "map to guest"
Ignoring unknown parameter "map to guest"
Unknown parameter encountered: "usershare allow guests"
Ignoring unknown parameter "usershare allow guests"
Unknown parameter encountered: "username map"
Ignoring unknown parameter "username map"
Unknown parameter encountered: "writeable"
Ignoring unknown parameter "writeable"
Unknown parameter encountered: "guest ok"
Ignoring unknown parameter "guest ok"
module samba_dsdb initialization failed : No such object
Unable to load modules for /var/lib/samba/private/sam.ldb: dsdb_module_search_dn: did not find base dn @ROOTDSE (0 results)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/samba/setup/upgradeprovision", line 1716, in <module>
    ldbs = get_ldbs(paths, creds, session, lp)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/samba/upgradehelpers.py", line 156, in get_ldbs
    ldbs.sam = SamDB(paths.samdb, session_info=session, credentials=creds, lp=lp, options=["modules:samba_dsdb"])
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/samba/samdb.py", line 55, in __init__
    options=options)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/samba/__init__.py", line 114, in __init__
    self.connect(url, flags, options)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/samba/samdb.py", line 69, in connect
    options=options)
_ldb.LdbError: (80, 'dsdb_module_search_dn: did not find base dn @ROOTDSE (0 results)')
dpkg: error processing samba4 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

Can anyone provide any assistance?

Comment: Can you split this up into two questions? This system works best when you post one question per post, thanks!

Comment: Sorry about that. I had about 5 questions that I broke into separate posts already I just felt that these two were similar enough for there to not need separation. Also I must apologize to the moderators for having questions that needed reformatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, I had a very similar problem. It is with your Samba set-up. The problem will affect all downloads from Software centre (including updates) and will chuck up errors when you uninstall.

Run the following command in terminal.

```
sudo apt-get purge samba4
```

That's all you need to do.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks. I take it this is because I chose not to change anything with my samba installation?